# Is it possible to check with git if there are any changes without actually collecting all the changes?

Tags: git, powershell

I would like to know if there are any changes in the given directory, except the Metadata folder. Here is my git command for that (I use Powershell):

```
git -C $WorkspaceRoot diff --name-only -r --no-renames "${FirstMergeParent}..HEAD" -- . :^Metadata
```

However, this returns all the changes. On a big repository with many changes this is likely to take time, am I right? I want to reduce this time, because I just need to know if there are changes, not all the changes.

So I could probably use pipeline:

```
git -C $WorkspaceRoot diff --name-only -r --no-renames "${FirstMergeParent}..HEAD" -- . :^Metadata | Select-Object -First 1
```

I am curious though if it is possible to achieve it without using piping and without using the `--quiet` flag, because I would still like to get a name of one changed file, so that I could output it as a reason for failing the test.

My interest is academic, because pipeline is good enough a solution. But I am curious if there is a purely git solution satisfying the stated conditions.

Comment: If you don't need a filename as a reason, you could maybe use [`--shortstat`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---shortstat)  `2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)`  Probably not any quicker though

Answer (score 1):

*You could do this in two steps:*

Use the `--quiet` option first to suppress the output and return an *exit code*. With this you can quickly verify if the test succeeds or fails. It is basically the *assert*-statement. If the exit-code is `0`, there are no differences and your test is successful.

If the exit-code is `1`, your test fails. Now you can run the `diff` command without the `--quiet` option to show all files with differences (your *failure*-message). Don't limit this output the first file since it is possible that several files with differences exist.

Comment: So it is enough to me to have just one result, not all. I am curious - does `--quiet` exit as soon as any difference is found? Common sense says it should. Whether calling git 2 times is acceptable depends on how often does the happy path happen and how big the repository is. Ours is pretty big and the happy path of having no changes is not that often. So, I guess I will have to stick with the piping approach, because it calls git just once. +1 for the idea, though. Thank you.

Comment: @mark Yes, this is why I proposed this answer in the first place. According to the source code it will exit early (see [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/97eea85a0a1ec66d356567808a1e4ca2367e0ce7/diff.c#L5582) and [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/97eea85a0a1ec66d356567808a1e4ca2367e0ce7/diff.c#L6751)). I was able to confirm this by debugging *git-diff*.